# Vue directive doesn't work on render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, render

I have a render function as follow

```
function renderCheckbox(data, type, row, meta) {
  return `<input type='checkbox' value='test' v-model='somedata' />`
}

const test = new Vue({
        el: '#just-test',

        data: {
            somedata: []
        }
```

In the template I have {{somedata}} to test it out.

The directive seems to not be working there. No value returns when render.
The v-model appears to be an attribute and the HTML when inspected looks to be:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="test" v-model="somedata">
```

However, if I write the statement directly to the template, v-model works.
Therefore, {{somedata}} appears as [ "test" ] when render. 
Any explanation and solution regarding to this?

Comment: And how do you use your renderCheckbox function?

Comment: The function is passing in as a value for another component A.
Component A has the render function which takes in HTML and render it

Answer (score 1):

Your render-function should create javascript. For example:

```
Vue.component('anchored-heading', {
  render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement(
      'h' + this.level,   // tag name
      this.$slots.default // array of children
    )
  }
})
```

Please use a template for html-like syntax.